# Input Field Live Validation Using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, jsp, input

Actually i have two text input boxes in my html page..

```
    <input id="input1" title="Text1">
    <input id="input2" title="Text2">
```

Now i want to live validate on second Input field using First text Input box...

Example for live validation [Live Validation](http://livevalidation.com/examples#exampleHomepage)

Please give me some sample code for Live validation in Jquery..
    jQuery("#input2").live('change', function() {

```
        if("#input1==#input2") {
            alert('Both are same');
        }   

        else{
            alert('both are not same'); 
        }
    });
```

But it is error..

Comment: Stackoverflow doesn't work that way: please give it a try first and if you run into problems with **your** code then you can ask here.

Comment: Actually i donot know how to do in Jquery...

Comment: jquery.validate plugin will help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't really enough given in your question, but assuming that you've already read through the link you provided and have already implemented a similar validation function, if you're simply wanting to call a validation function every time the content of a `text` input field changes you'd simply:

```
$('input[type="text"]').on('input', function() {
    myValidationFunction();
})
```

[This quick JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AKUYh/1) I've whipped up changes a paragraph's text whenever the input's text changes, and should point you in the right direction.

You'll benefit a lot by working through the official jQuery tutorial: http://try.jquery.com/

Comment: i'm asking live validation..

Comment: Well you haven't really asked a question. StackOverflow isn't a "give me code" it's an "I've tried this but it I'm having problems". Your comment on your question suggested that you had implemented a validation function but weren't sure how to call it. My answer here hopefully gives you a start point. Equally the source you've linked to lead me to assume you already had this in place.